# Combination of checkboxes in streamlit app

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am building stream lit app, I know how to define if option_1 is chosen do something, but what if a user choose option 1 and option 2? I want the code doesn't runs if a user select anything rather than only option_1, even a combination of option_1 or option_2.

````
option_1 = st.sidebar.checkbox('df1', value=True)
option_2 = st.sidebar.checkbox('df2')
option_3 = st.sidebar.checkbox('df3')



if option_1: 
   "do something"  ```
````

Comment: Are you looking for `if option_1 and option_2:`?

Comment: No I explained it the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an `if`/`else if` statement.

```
option_1 = st.sidebar.checkbox('df1', value=True)
option_2 = st.sidebar.checkbox('df2')
option_3 = st.sidebar.checkbox('df3')

if option_1 and option_2: 
   st.write("Selected option 1 and option 1")
else if option_1:
   st.write("Selected just option 1")
else if option_2:
   st.write("Selected just option 2")
```